# Reading raw image files in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, image, decode

How do i decode/open raw image files like .CR2 or .NEF and .ARW without having the codec installed, something like lightroom open raw files ? My code look like this:

```
if (fe == "CR2" | fe == "NEF" | fe == "ARW" )
{
    BitmapDecoder bmpDec = BitmapDecoder.Create(new Uri(op.FileName), BitmapCreateOptions.DelayCreation, BitmapCacheOption.None);

    BitmapSource bsource = bmpDec.Frames[0];
    info_box.Content = fe;
    imgControl.Source = bsource;
}
```

***This work only with the raw codecs installed and dont work with ARW format.***

Comment: Well without any codec installed, how do you expect anything to understand the data? If you know about the file format yourself, you could read the raw data and create an appropriate bitmap source with that... but something needs to understand the very basics (size, per-pixel format, palette or whatever).

Comment: A codec is like a driver, it tells the computer how to interpret the data.  Without it, the computer doesn't know what to do with the data unless you write your own decoder.

Comment: Do you know any intructions/lessons where i can start?

Comment: "TheGreatCO" i know...

Comment: Try doing a Google search for "open source raw editor" or "open source raw conversion". Here's the first link I found: http://rawstudio.org/ Trying to implement your own processing for digital camera raw files could keep you busy for a year or so ...

Comment: When you want to answer a commenter, like TheGreatCO, what you should do is put "@" in front, @TheGreatCo - StackOverflow will show a popup that you can select with your mouse. The advantage is that TheGreatCO then gets notified that you've answered him/her.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have a codec installed, then you'll have to read the raw image data and convert it to a bitmap or other format that you *can* read. In order to do that, you need a copy of the format specification so that you can write code that reads the binary data.

I strongly recommend getting a codec, or finding code that somebody has written that already handles the conversion. But if you really want to try your hand at writing image format conversion code, your first order of business is to get the format specification.

A quick Google search on [CR2 image format] reveals this [Canon CR2 Specification](http://wildtramper.com/sw/cr2/cr2.html). Truthfully, I don't know how accurate that is, but it looks reasonable. A little time with a search engine will probably reveal similar documents for the other formats.

Be forewarned: writing these conversions can be a very difficult task. Again, I recommend that you find some existing code that you can leverage.

Comment: Where can i learn writing image format conversion code as a beginner programer ?

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on not installing a codec, then your best bet might be these:

http://www.cybercom.net/~dcoffin/dcraw/
- written in C, supports most cameras

http://sourceforge.net/projects/dcrawnet/
- apparently a (partial?) port of DCRAW to C#, but project does not seem to be active